# Adding/Removing Rows

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I've been trying to make rows dynamically appear based on hitting the submit button from a form using Bootstrap 3. I can enter one name, hit submit and the row (or panel I suppose) appears like it is supposed to, but when I enter a second name, the row previously created just gets overwritten with the name, and I am not sure why. I'm trying to implement this on utilizing a php file because I want to values to be sent through a curl and use a rest interface, but the issue is getting my rows to work.

The question I have: Why is only one row being created instead of multiple copies, as I planned.

Here is my code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Jquery Add More Field Example</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Add/Remove Names</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form>
                <input type='hidden'  name ='topic' value='<?=$topic?>' onchange="rememberField(this)"/>&nbsp;
                <div class="input-group control-group after-add-more">
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name Here">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default add-more">Submit</button>

                </div>
            </form>


            <!-- Copy Fields -->
            <div class="copy">
            <div class="control-group input-group" style="margin-top:10px">
                <?php $name = $_GET['name']; ?><p><?=$name?></p>
                <div class="input-group-btn"> 
                <button class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Remove</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $(".add-more").click(function(){ 
          var html = $(".copy").html();
          $(".after-add-more").after(html);
      });
      $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){ 
          $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
      });


    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your form is getting submitted hence your page is being reloaded. You need to either: use Ajax or store the list server side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the name attribute in the input field from

`name="name"`

to

`name="name[]"`